# How can I create unique identifiers for each machine in Linux or Perl?

Tags: linux, perl

I have a Perl script running in many machines, the script will store some data into a MySQL Database. I need to know the source of data.

I cannot use hostname , because some machines's hostname is 'localhost'.

`ifconfig` gives random devices and IP, some `eth0`,some `eth1`,some other device name.

Is there any other way to create unique identifiers for each machine? And everytime I run the Perl script, this unique identifier does not change.

Comment: What pieces of common, reliable, unique information/hardware/whatever do these machines have? Which OS do they run on? Without these bits of info any answer you get will resemble random crap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from `dmidecode` provides a number of hardware UUID & serial numbers which your perl script could take advantage of.  To quote the man page for dmidecode:

> ```
>   dmidecode  is a tool for dumping a computer's DMI (some say SMBIOS) table
>   contents in a human-readable format. This table contains a description
>   of  the  system's  hardware  components,  as well as other useful
>   pieces of information such as serial numbers and BIOS revision.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try uuid.

uuid - DCE compatible Universally Unique Identifier library

[here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/uuid)

Comment: Hi,Everytime I run uuidgen, the output diffs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [hostid](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hostid), in addition with a previous call to [genhostid](http://linux.die.net/man/1/genhostid) that will generate and store the unique id for the machine (so it won't change at each call).

Comment: `hostid` (GNU) seems hightly related to the host real ip and it is not POSIX (see [GNU libc - hostid](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Host-Identification.html)).

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is to generate a file with a random ID the first time, and use the file contents once the file exists. I put it in /etc somewhere, but it doesn't matter.

This is tolerant of system configuration changes, but requires some extra work to interrogate remotely.

Answer (score -1):

take MAC address and modify it?

```
ipconfig -a
```

or

```
arp
```

and parse?

Comment: Won't the MAC address be the same under both Windows and Linux on the same machine if it's burned into the ROM? (Also some MAC addresses are locally assigned  -there's a bit that indicates this, these can't possibly be globally unique)

Comment: Yes - It will be the same in windows and linux - but I didn't get how it is relevant. However the second point is important, MAC addresses of network cards can indeed be assigned although I am not sure whether people do that often [given that MAC address of network cards are already globally unique]. Also I assume you are saying ROM of network cards, as ROM of the machine is irrelevant for the discussion [it doesn't store the MAC address]